# Pass data to same Controller from 2 different jquerys in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

My project consists on making an OCR read on an image from coordinates drawn by the user.So i have made 2 external javascripts one manipulates the rectangles and the second manipulates the file(delete, preview..)

FileUpload.JS

```
function saveImage() {
var file = $("#imageBrowser").get(0).files;
var data = new FormData;
data.append("ImageFile", file[0]);
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "/OcrImage/OcrOnImage",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    
  })
 }
```

RectangleDrawing.js

```
$(function () {
$('#btnSend').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(boundingBoxes),
        url: "/OcrImage/OcrOnImage",
    });
    });
});
```

the Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OcrOnImage(ImageUploadModel objeImageViewModel, Coordinate[] Coordinates)
    {//code}
```

My question is how can i pass data from each javascripts to a single controller through a single submit.Keep in mind that i have tried to upload the file using razorview and i could pass only one data which is either Coordinates or the file to upload.

If there's a better method to do this please let know with an example.Thank you in advance.
I can provide more info if not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to file upload with view models (in your case ImageUploadModel)  then you need to consider two things.

1. Your view model should contains a property of type HttpPostedFileBase like below:

   HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
2. You should have strongly typed view with model bindings. something like below:

```html
@model ImageUploadModel
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImageUpload)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ImageUpload)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
```

You could use @using (Html.BeginForm()) { ... } helper alternative to using form if you want to but for fileupload you must have this enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute.

Controller code would be like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult OcrOnImage(ImageUploadModel model)
{
    var validImageTypes = new string[]
    {
        "image/gif",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/pjpeg",
        "image/png"
    }

    if (model.ImageUpload == null || model.ImageUpload.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "This field is required");
    }
    else if (!imageTypes.Contains(model.ImageUpload.ContentType))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "Please choose either a GIF, JPG or PNG image.");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var image = new Image
        {
            Title = model.Title,
            AltText = model.AltText,
            Caption = model.Caption
        }

        if (model.ImageUpload != null && model.ImageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var uploadDir = "~/uploads"
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadDir), model.ImageUpload.FileName);
            var imageUrl = Path.Combine(uploadDir, model.ImageUpload.FileName);
            model.ImageUpload.SaveAs(imagePath);
            image.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        db.Create(image);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I have never faced like this situation where file upload and another action is going with along , it is some violation of SRP (single responsibility principle). By the way you can try coordination with js as you described above on putting Coordinate list/array in controller action like below and let me is that works or not.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult OcrOnImage(ImageUploadModel model,Coordinate[] Coordinates) {//like above}
```